# DirectX 9 couldn't draw line when vertex buffer changes data

Tags: c++, directx-9, vertex-buffer

I'm trying to draw a line with the start point or end point of the line changing over time (i.e. have new positions every frame), but it's not working.

I have created the vertex buffer by using the usage of `D3DUSAGE_WRITEONLY | D3DUSAGE_DYNAMIC` and setting the pool to `D3DPOOL_DEFAULT`, but it doesn't show anything when I change the vertices.

In fact, the line only shows and draws when the vertices data inside the buffer doesn't change. Can someone please let me know whats wrong with it?

Heres the code I've got:

**Line.h**

```
#include"Mesh.h"

class Line : public Mesh
{
public:
    Line(D3DCOLOR color, D3DXVECTOR3 startPoint, D3DXVECTOR3 endPoint);
    virtual ~Line();

    void SetPoints(D3DXVECTOR3 startPoint, D3DXVECTOR3 endPoint);

    void Draw();
};
```

**Line.cpp**

```
#include"Line.h"

Line::Line(D3DCOLOR color, D3DXVECTOR3 startPoint, D3DXVECTOR3 endPoint) : Mesh()
{
    vertexCount = 2;
    vertices = new VERTEX[vertexCount];

    VERTEX vertex;
    vertex.position = startPoint;
    vertex.color = color;
    vertices[0] = vertex;

    vertex.position = endPoint;
    vertex.color = color;
    vertices[1] = vertex;

    DirectX::device->CreateVertexBuffer(sizeof(VERTEX) * vertexCount, D3DUSAGE_WRITEONLY | D3DUSAGE_DYNAMIC, VERTEXFORMAT, D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, &vertexBuffer, NULL);

    VOID* vertexLocking;
    vertexBuffer->Lock(0, 0, (void**)&vertexLocking, 0);
    memcpy(vertexLocking, vertices, sizeof(VERTEX) * vertexCount);
    vertexBuffer->Unlock();
}

Line::~Line()
{

}

void Line::SetPoints(D3DXVECTOR3 startPoint, D3DXVECTOR3 endPoint)
{
    vertices[0].position = startPoint;
    vertices[1].position = endPoint;

    VOID* vertexLocking;
    vertexBuffer->Lock(0, 0, (void**)&vertexLocking, D3DLOCK_DISCARD);
    memcpy(vertexLocking, vertices, sizeof(VERTEX) * vertexCount);
    vertexBuffer->Unlock();

}

void Line::Draw()
{
    UINT passNum = 4;
    DirectX::currentShaderEffect->Begin(&passNum, 0);
    DirectX::currentShaderEffect->BeginPass(4);

    DirectX::device->SetStreamSource(0, vertexBuffer, 0, sizeof(VERTEX));
    DirectX::device->SetVertexDeclaration(DirectX::vertexDec);
    DirectX::device->DrawPrimitive(D3DPT_LINELIST, 0, 1);

    DirectX::currentShaderEffect->EndPass();
    DirectX::currentShaderEffect->End();
}
```

Comment: How did you change the point position, can you paste that code?